# How to get first-order optimality from scipy.optimize module

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

If I have this equation f(v,R,xi)=2/v*((((((v*t0/2)+R))**2+((xi-x0)**2))**0.5)-R).

How to get the first-order optimality from that equation when I use that equation to get min v,R using scipy.optimize.leastsq ?

I don't have problem to get min v,R using scipy.optimize.leastsq but I get confused when I want get first-order optimality...

Thanks for your attention :D. Happy New Year

Comment: We'll need more than this....

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573788/how-to-get-first-order-optimality-with-python-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "first-order optimality" with python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573788/how-to-get-first-order-optimality-with-python-script)