# How to get "first-order optimality" with python script

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I curious about how to get "first-order optimality" value using python script.
For optimatization python has many module like scipy.optimize and openopt. But I confused how to use that module to get first-order optimality

This is sample matlab script to get first-order optimality

```
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda]= lsqcurvefit(func,x0,xdata,tdata);
foo = output.firstorderopt %get first-order optimality value
```

this is some of foo reference from mathworks
[here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/brhkghv-45.html)

Thanks for your attention, Happy New Year 2011  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [scipy.linalg.basic.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html) or [scipy.optimize.minpack.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Try to write your own code, refer to the tutorials or else search the web for `scipy.linalg.basic.lstsq` for code samples (there are some out there). If you encounter any issues, post the code and the issue here.